# What is posix, and how can I elevate my permissions using python?

Tags: python, posix

I was wondering if I could elevate my permissions on a chromebook with the os posix using a python script. I was not given the administrative permissions when I was given the laptop for college.

Comment: "...  with the os posix  ..." could not parse.

Comment: Operating System posix http://searchenterpriselinux.techtarget.com/definition/POSIX here is a link to what I was referring to

Comment: Your link doesn't show any way to make sense of the phrase "Operating System posix".

Answer (score 4):

From wikipedia:

> POSIX, an acronym for Portable Operating System Interface, is a family of standards specified by the IEEE Computer Society for maintaining compatibility between operating systems. POSIX defines the application programming interface (API), along with command line shells and utility interfaces, for software compatibility with variants of Unix and other operating systems.

POSIX has nothing to do with your problem, and python (or any other language) cannot help you with acquiring root (administrative) privileges on your machine.